# Does this lemma have a more common name?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Consider a function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$. If $f'(c)>0,$ then there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that $f:(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing. If $f'(c)<0$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ so that $f:(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly decreasing.

Is there a common name for this lemma? I am trying to find an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong and therefore has no name.
Let $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x+x^2&x\in\Bbb Q\\x&x\notin \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$
Then $f'(0)=1$, but $f$ is not strictly increasing on any open interval.

Comment: Even in cases where $f'$ exists on a neighborhood of $c$, $f'$ is known to have the intermediate value property, but is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Is this function continuous?

Comment: If this is not continuous anywhere how is it differentiable? I am confused because I can take the derivative easily but doesn't differetiability imply continuity?

Comment: @ryBear This function is both continuous and differentiable at $c=0$ (but nowhere else). You can verify that by simply applying the definitions.

Comment: If you want an everywhere differentiable counterexample, something like $$f(x)=x+(e^x-1-x)\sin^2(1/x^2)$$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$ should work.

Answer (score 1):

You  may draw the conclusion that there's an $\epsilon$ such that $f(a)<f(b)$ for all $a\in ]c-\epsilon,c[$ and $b\in]c,c+\epsilon[$.  But that doesn't mean that $f$ is increasing, cf. Hagen's example.

Btw: Being a German, I know that fact is called "Punktaler Vergleichssatz" (punctual comparison theorem?).